# How to pronounce “arch” in Linuxese?

Tags: pronunciation, slang, terminology

*Tech* stands for *technique* or *technology*. But how should one pronounce *tech*?  Is it as /tɛk/ as in *technical* or /tɛtʃ/ as in *tetchy*?

Similarly, *arch* stands for *architect* or *architecture*. How do you pronounce *arch*? Is it the same way you do when you say the *Golden Arches*,  or it it as in *archangel* with a /k/ sound?

Comment: Be warned that Donald Knuth’s TeX typesetting system is expected to be pronounced /ˈtɛx/, as though it were Greek, like in *τεχνικ*.  The /x/ is the sound at the end of Scottish *loch* or German *Bach*, but it often comes out as /k/ by English-speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Despite merely being an abbreviation of the word "architecture" in this context, "arch" is still pronounced **[ar-ch]** here.

Comment: If he means the */usr/bin/arch* command, then sure, it’s pronounced [ɑɹtʃ]. But I’m not sure that’s the word he means.

Comment: Both the command and the abbreviation are pronounced in this manner. The "arch" command's output is the type of "architecture" the OS is running. I'm answering the question indicated in the title. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arch

Comment: Yeah, ok.  I can’t say I know a context for ever giving some hypothetical *arch* term of art an actual [ɑɹk] pronunciation in Unixese.